# Cant send data back using with method

Tags: laravel

Please guys I am redirecting back to a route with a variable, but I keep getting variable undefined at the view if i die dump record variable. here is my code

```
public function postSearchPatientMedicalRecords(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
           'patientReg'=>'required|present|exists:patient,patient_id'
        ]);
        $patient = Patients::where('patient_id','=',$request->input('patientReg'));
        $records = $patient->first()->myRecords()->orderBy('records.created_at','desc');
        return redirect()->route('records')->with('record',$records);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the view and the entire error?

Comment: try this `return redirect('records')->with('record', $records);`    use this in blade `{{ session('record') }}`

Comment: you can pass record id to route.

Comment: This happens most time to laravel 5 upgrade to 8...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirect the search result. you can render the search result template under the code to show your search result. 
But then you have to design your routes for both get and post for example.

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'login', 'AuthController@login');
```

you can just redirect id or any message but this will be one time usable using session flash.

Answer (score 0):

To Redirect back you can use

```
return redirect()->back()->with('record',$records);
```

And access the records in your blade using

```
Session::get('record')
```

Comment: this is exactly what i first tried but still same problem it keeps saying undefined variable record and i sent it in the with method

Comment: Can you show your blade how you access the variable @spartyboy

Answer (score -1):

Change record to records inside with as shown below

```
return redirect()->route('records')->with('records',$records);
```